# Load Student data from file into a list

Tags: c#, list, file

I am very new to c#. But, I want to load data from a .txt file and then automatically that data to fill my list. How can I do it?

I want in the ReadFromFile function to be able to automatically fill the list with data from the file. Because after that when I call my SortData function I want to use the data from the file and not add all data again manually.

I managed to load the data from the file but have trouble filling the list after that.

Here is my .txt file

```
 Name: Bob   Position: CEO   Intern: 7   Salary: 7000
 Name: Toti  Position: Freelancer    Intern: 4   Salary: 4000
 Name: Mike  Position: www   Intern: 5   Salary: 5000
 Name: Vanko     Position: Badass    Intern: 5   Salary: 5000
```

Here is my ReadFromFile function:

```
    //READ FROM FILE
    public static void ReadFromFile(List<Student> existingStudents, string 
filePath)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
        }
        reader.Close();

        foreach (Student stud in existingStudents)
        {
            existingStudents.Add(new Student(stud.id, stud.Name, stud.Position, stud.Internship));
            Console.WriteLine(stud.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I also have class Student with the following properties:

```
class Student
    {
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public double salary;
    public string position;
    public int intern;

    public Student(int id, string name, string position, int intern)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.intern = intern;
    }
 }
```

In the main function I call add the functions:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Student> st = new List<Student>();

        String filePath = "test.txt";
        switch (answer)
              {
                case 1:
                    WriteToFile(st, filePath);
                    Console.WriteLine("File Created!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ReadFromFile(st, filePath);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    AddStudent(st);
                    break;
   } while (answer != 4);
  }
```

Comment: First question is why you do not use sql? It is much easier to use for this type.

Comment: I know it is easier in sql, but I have to do the task using only c#.

Comment: A better signature for your method would be `public static List<Student> ReadFromFile(string filePath)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i wrote for situation you have but it needs a little optimization of text file formatting.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name;
    public string Position;
    public string Intern;
    public string Salary;
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] yourFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:PathToFile\File.txt");

        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

        foreach(string s in yourFile)
        {
            Student student = new Student();

            string[] dividedLines = s.Split('|');
            foreach(string line in dividedLines)
            {                    
                string[] data = line.Split(':');
                switch(data[0])
                {
                    case "Name":
                    student.Name = data[1];
                    break;
                    case "Position":
                    student.Position = data[1];
                    break;
                    case "Intern":
                    student.Intern= data[1];
                    break;
                    case "Salary":
                    student.Salary = data[1];
                    break;
                }
            }
            students.Add(student);
        }
    }
}
```

it could be easier if your line in your text file is written like this:

`Bob|Ceo|7|7000`

because we would have to use only one split.

With this you have data stored in `List` and if you want to display some students data you can easily find it inside list by name or just do `foreach(Student s in students)` and it will give you each student

Comment: Thank you. I will test it later today and will let you know if i have any questions.

Comment: I don't understand where exactly you add the data from the file into the list? Can you explain?

Comment: You see `string[] yourFile`, instead of that use array of lines from your file

Comment: I am confused with your code. Instead of  string[] yourFile, I use String filePath = "test.txt"; And it does not fill the list. Did you manage to fill the list on your end?

Comment: Also, I think that "string s in yourFile" in the foreach has to be "foreach (Student s in st)". Otherwise it cannot convert from Student type to string?

Comment: You are not getting that you need to set your file into `string[] yourFile` so i have edited it and done it myself. And no it has to be foreach string since we are looping through `string[]` array not `Student[]` array

Comment: Also i have made some changes so it is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I've modified your `Student` class to be a little more idiomatic and to also accept the fields from your source file in to the constructor. It now looks like:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Intern { get; set; }

    public Student(string name, string position, int intern, decimal salary)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Position = position;
        this.Intern = intern;
        this.Salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Then, given I can change your `ReadFromFile` method signature to also be more idiomatic, I created this:

```
public static List<Student> ReadFromFile(string filePath)
{
    var students =
        from line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        let parts =
            line
                .Trim()
                .Split('\t')
                .Select(x => x.Trim().Split(':').Select(y => y.Trim()).ToArray())
                .ToDictionary(y => y[0], y => y[1])
        select new Student(parts["Name"], parts["Position"], int.Parse(parts["Intern"]), decimal.Parse(parts["Salary"]));

    return students.ToList();
}
```

Now your code looks like this:

```
List<Student> students = ReadFromFile(filePath);
```

---

As per your comment this is how I would modify your code:

```
public class Student
{
    private int _next_id = 0;
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Intern { get; set; }

    public Student(string name, string position, int intern, decimal salary)
    {
        this.Id = _next_id++;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Position = position;
        this.Intern = intern;
        this.Salary = salary;
    }
}
```

That auto-increments the Student Id.

Here's the `AddStudent` method (which I changed to a `private static IEnumerable<Student> AskForStudents()` method):

```
private static IEnumerable<Student> AskForStudents()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter new student information");
```

//          int id = -1;
//          do
//          {
//              Console.Write(" 1. Enter student Id: ");
//          } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out id));

```
        Console.Write(" 2. Enter student Name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write(" 3. Enter student Job Title: ");
        string jobTitle = Console.ReadLine();

        int yrsOfService = -1;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(" 4. Enter student years of service: ");
        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out yrsOfService));

        decimal salary = -1m;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(" 4. Enter salary: ");
        } while (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out salary));

        yield return new Student(name, jobTitle, yrsOfService, salary);

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another Student? y/n");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "n")
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

You would now use it like this:

```
var students = ReadFromFile(filePath);
students.AddRange(AskForStudents());
```

Comment: Hey, it worked perfectly. But, that id seems a little odd there. Do you know how to make it auto incremented and every time I add new Student I want to create automatically a new id. I think I have to modify my addStudent() function. Here is my addStudent() function: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpuwpforpk1l9h6/addStudent.txt?dl=0

Comment: Thank you. I will try it tomorrow and will ask you if i have any questions.

Comment: I don't think yield return new Student(name, jobTitle, yrsOfService, salary); should be there, because I am not adding the Student to the list, I think I should replace it with that line: existingStudents.Add(new Student(name, jobTitle, yrsOfService, salary));

Comment: Sorry, maybe my explanation was not clear. I see that way I am incrementing the id, but I have to attach the id to the Student and then add it to the file together with the ID.

Comment: @Kaloyan - You're writing methods in an inside out way. You should **not** do `existingStudents.Add(new Student(name, jobTitle, yrsOfService, salary));`. You should do `existingStudents.AddRange(AskForStudents());` - as I did it in my question. That's the right way to write composable and testable programs.